# gyp error in vs19 project. I am new to node and visual studio. When I try npm install in the angular project, I get this gyp error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cmd, npm-install, gyp

---

##Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in 
sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp_*init*_.py", line 545, in script_main
return main(sys.argv[1:])
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp_*init*_.py", line 538, in main
return gyp_main(args)
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp_*init*_.py", line 514, in gyp_main
options.duplicate_basename_check)
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp_*init*_.py", line 98, in Load
generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1916, in CalculateVariables
generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
File "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2019'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\Users\vanil\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\vanil\Snap\Server\MADP.Server\Snap.ManagementConsole\Public\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1